# UBUNTU 14.04 - Rstudio - unable to install ggmap library

Tags: linux, rstudio, ubuntu-14.04, ggmap

I'm trying to install ggmap library in my Rstudio but I get the following error:

```
ERROR: dependency ‘rjson’ is not available for package ‘ggmap’.
```

Is there any other way of installing it, I tried via menu Tools - Install packages or via console with command install.packages("ggmap").

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wild guess (for missing dependency):

```
sudo apt-get install r-base r-base-dev

sudo apt-get install r-cran-rjson
```

[Filelist of r-cran-rjson package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/r-cran-rjson/filelist)

*or* installation from Launchpad:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:opencpu/rstudio
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rstudio-server
```

[Please see this reference for details](http://www.thertrader.com/2014/09/22/installing-rrstudio-on-ubuntu-14-04/)

Comment: Thank you ajaaskel, i had the base but I didn't have the r-cran-rjson, so this code "sudo apt-get install r-cran-rjson" saved me :D Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

first install rjson library using command prompt

```
install.packages("rjson",depend =TRUE)
```

Now install ggmap library
 
1.install.packages("rjson",depend =TRUE)
          OR
2.Download and unzip

```
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggmap/index.html
```

If it doesn't work do

```
update.packages(repos="http://cran.revolutionanalytics.com")
```

Answer (score 0):

Best Way is to open synaptic :

- tap rjson
- right-click ( select for installation )
- apply
- close synaptic
  and in R session install.packages("ggmap")

[image]